# How to prevent my crossfilter from selecting nothing - dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working on a project using dc.js and I don't want the crossfilter to render unless data is selected. Currently, it is possible to do something like this
[image]

Is there a way to avoid this from happening? I want at least one bar to have to be selected to crossfilter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. you need to add the following two lines to your bar chart:

```
.round(dc.round.floor)
.alwaysUseRounding(true)
```

If your bar chart has the property .centerBar(true), you should use the following instead:

```
.round(function(n) { return Math.floor(n) + 0.5 })
.alwaysUseRounding(true)
```